# GraphQL & NestJs @ResolveField: How to access the Parent of the Parent

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

In NestJs, Lets say we have a GQL model:

```
User {
  _id
  role
  profile {
    firstName
    birthDate
    // RESOLVED FIELD:
    isEditable
  }
}
```

And i have the following Resolver

```
@Resolver((of: any) => Profile)
export class ProfileResolver {
  @ResolveField((returns) => Boolean, { nullable: false })
  async isEditable(@Parent() user: User) {
    // i need to acces user.role to find out if the profile is editable
    // but when using @Parent or @Root i get the Profile instead of the User
  }
}
```

How can i access the User in that FieldResolver? As mentioned in the comment in the code, i only get the Profile when using @Parent or @Root.